# What is the default of numpy functions, with where=False?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

The [ufunc documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-kwargs) states:

> where
>
> New in version 1.7.
> Accepts a boolean array which is broadcast together with the operands. Values of True indicate to calculate the ufunc at that position, values of False indicate to leave the value in the output alone.

What is the default behavior, when `out` is not given?

I observed some behavior, which doesn't really make sense to me:

```
import numpy as np
a,b = np.ones((2,2))
np.add(a,b,where = False) #returns 0
np.exp(a, where = False)  #returns 1
np.sin(a, where = False)  #returns 1
np.sign(a, where = False) #returns 0
np.reciprocal(a, where = False) #returns 0
```

Does anyone know the underlying reason/behavior?
Especially `np.reciprocal` doesn't really make sense, as the reciprocal value can never be 0

EDIT: The behavior is even more complex:

```
a,b = np.ones(2)
np.add(a,b,where = False) #returns 6.0775647498958414e-316
a,b = 1,1
np.add(a,b, where = False) #returns 12301129, 
#running this line several times doesn't give the same result every time...
```

I'm using Numpy version 1.11.1

Comment: You're first line raises a `ValueError`; the other lines also look awkward. Could you make an actual runnable example to test?

Comment: NB: it may be my reading, but `False` is not a boolean array. Perhaps the functions cast it to one, but it's not what the documentation states.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: the second raises `ValueError: Automatic allocation was requested for an iterator operand, and it was flagged as readable, but buffering  without delayed allocation was enabled`. That's for NumPy 1.13.

Comment: Fun fact: the same line for NumPy 1.11 does not raise an exception, but returns -1.4916681462400413e-154. Definitely smaller than `np.finfo(np.float64).eps`, thus 0, but not an integer.

Comment: It's not more complex, it's incorrect because it's being used incorrectly. It is actually a bug in NumPy, and should raise an exception. Not the one in my other comment: that's Python 3 catching a problem in NumPy. Python 2 doesn't catch this problem, and as a result, you get unpredictable (undefined?) behaviour.

Comment: You may want to raise an issue on the NumPy issue tracker, and point people to this question. I don't think NumPy should behave as such.

Comment: @MSeifert: I see you've edited the question. Any suggestion perhaps?

Comment: It's tricky because `where` without `out` simply doesn't make much sense because neither the ufunc-identity nor zero make any sense as "default value" in the returned array. I guess it's just allocating an `np.empty_like(a)` out array and then you're stuck with "random values" especially if you define `where=False` and don't put any values in the newly created array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like garbage becasue that's exactly what it is - memory that's been garbage collected.

Whatever function you are calling sets aside a block of memory to put the results in, but never puts any results there because `where=False`.  You're getting the same values you would from `np.empty` - i.e. whatever garbage was in that memory block before the function assigned it.